# Sed to replace first forward slash in line after match with a string

Tags: unix, sed, awk

So I have the following in a file:

```
/icon.png
/my/path/tester/icon.png
/logo.png
/my/path/tester/logo.png
```

I want to replace all lines that do NOT contain 'tester' and add '/my/path/tester/' to the beginning... leaving:

```
/my/path/tester/icon.png
/my/path/tester/icon.png
/my/path/tester/logo.png
/my/path/tester/logo.png
```

I would also prefer to edit the file in place using sed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you have a `sed` that supports the `-i` option (eg, gnu-sed):

```
sed -i '/tester/!s@^@/my/path/tester@' file
```

Note that this does what you ask for, but is not robust.  You probably want to limit the replacement to lines that do not match '/tester/' rather than 'tester', and there really is no point to the `-i` option (see [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-the-file-in-place/12696585#12696585)).  Using `-i` obfuscates the temporary file, which for some reason people often do not want and think they avoid by using `-i`.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfect from the cmd line but within a script it throws: unterminated `s' command. Any thoughts?

Comment: Invalid quoting inside the script, or perhaps the script is used to generate another and '@@' has special meaning (eg, @...@ indicates a text replacement).  Otherwise, need more details on the script.  Try a different delimter.  (eg, replace @ with ! or something else)