# Using sed to remove a column from a CSV

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file where the fields are encapsulated with double quotes - general example of file:

```
"Internal ID", "External ID", "Name"
"123", "ABC", "ABC Incorporated"
```

Desired outcome, removing first column and saving the file back with the same name:

```
"External ID", "Name"
"ABC", "ABC Incorporated"
```

Can the above sed be modified to handle the "," delimiter? If so, how? Or are there better alternatives? Still a shell noob but I tried the following with no success:

```
    sed -i 's/[^'\"','\"']*,//' file.csv
```

Any help be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you want to remove the first column?

Comment: Yes, the first column is to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ sed 's/^.*\(".*", ".*"\)$/\1/' file
"External ID", "Name"
"ABC", "ABC Incorporated"
```

It prints the last two values.

```
$ sed 's/^"[^"]*", //' file
"External ID", "Name"
"ABC", "ABC Incorporated"
```

It removes the first value in a comma separated string.

Comment: +1, but you don't need `g` when your regex is anchored -- it can only match once per line.

Answer (score 3):

This is a job for `cut`.

```
 cut -d, -f 2- < file.csv
```

Use the shell to rename the output.  Or use the script named `inline` at [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-the-file-in-place/12696585#12696585) and invoke cut as:

```
inline file.csv cut -d, -f 2-
```

Answer (score 0):

quick way:

```
sed 's/[^,]*,\s*//' file
"External ID", "Name"
"ABC", "ABC Incorporated"
```

Note this would fail if your field contains comma like `"ABC,DEF","ABC Incor.."`

Answer (score 0):

Using Awk:

```
awk -F", " '{print substr($0, index($0,$2))}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```