# Deleting line in a shell script file using sed command

Tags: shell, unix, sed, text-files

I am trying to delete a line in a file by a certain keyword entered. The whole file content is then automatically displayed without the word entered (success). However, the file itself is still containing the word which should've been deleted.

This is the content of my file `smilies.txt`

```
:) smile
:( sad
;) wink
:D laughing
;( crying
:O surprise
:P tongue
:* kiss
:X nowords
:s confuse
```

This is my script:

```
echo 'Enter a smiley or its description you want to delete: '
read delsmiley
sed /"$delsmiley"/d smilies.txt
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sed commands are written as `sed "/x/d"` not `sed /"x"/d`. Given your posted file what would you expect to happen if someone entered "o"? What about ".*"? What about ":*"? What about "/"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed edit the file in place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-the-file-in-place)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use sed for this as sed ONLY operates on regular expressions and you need your file to be treated as fields of strings or you will have unsolvable (with sed) undesirable behavior problems given various user input (e.g. try your sed command with `delsmiley` set to `/`, `:*`, and `o`).

Use awk instead:

```
awk -v d="$delsmiley" '($1 != d) && ($2 != d)' smilies.txt > tmp &&
mv tmp smilies.txt
```

Gnu awk has a `-i inplace` option of you care about not explicitly specifying the tmp file name.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-i` (`--in-place`) option to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i /"$delsmiley"/d smilies.txt
```

`-i` option can be used with suffix; original file will be backuped.

```
sed -i.bak /"$delsmiley"/d smilies.txt
```

**UPDATE**

As Ed Morton, for some input above command will cause error. To avoid that you need to use other command that interpret input string as is. For example using `grep -v` with `-F` option:

```
grep -Fv "$delsmiley" smilies.txt > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp smilies.txt
```