# How do I edit a file after I shell to a Docker container?

Tags: docker, command-line-interface, editor

I successfully shelled to a Docker container using:

```
docker exec -i -t 69f1711a205e bash
```

Now I need to edit file and I don't have any editors inside:

```
root@69f1711a205e:/# nano
bash: nano: command not found
root@69f1711a205e:/# pico
bash: pico: command not found
root@69f1711a205e:/# vi
bash: vi: command not found
root@69f1711a205e:/# vim
bash: vim: command not found
root@69f1711a205e:/# emacs
bash: emacs: command not found
root@69f1711a205e:/#
```

How do I edit files?

Comment: @Opal I use confluent/postgres-bw:0.1

Comment: docker should install at lease on test editor ,at least vim by default

Comment: run following command to install 'nano' in the container

$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install nano

Comment: I am newbie, and I found you can also modify the file outside of docker using vim.

Answer (score 1070, accepted):

As in the comments, there's no default editor set - strange - the `$EDITOR` environment variable is empty. You can log in into a container with:

```
docker exec -it <container> bash
```

And run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim
```

Or use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM  confluent/postgres-bw:0.1

RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "vim"]
```

Docker images are delivered trimmed to the bare minimum - so no editor is installed with the shipped container. That's why there's a need to install it manually.

**EDIT**

I also encourage you to read my [post](https://blog.softwaremill.com/editing-files-in-a-docker-container-f36d76b9613c) about the topic.

Comment: Thank you for the VIM note. I am a beginner to docker. I have made some changes to some files with vim on bash, how do I apply these changes to the container? I used docker restart but it did't work

Comment: What you need is mounting a volume: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Comment: I needed to login as a root to get this done `docker exec -u 0 -it container_name bash`.

Comment: There's a proposal here to not use multiple FROMs in the dockerfile (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13026) so if that comes into fruition, the second solution may not work for everyone, but the non-dockerfile instructions worked for me, appreciated.

Comment: As with docker, better to install `vim-tiny` instead, probably.

Comment: Maybe you could consider not installing an editor in each container you attach to, but rather just once on the docker host machine. As other commentators mentioned you can mount the volume, so you can edit the files that are going to be mounted, or navigate to the container data itself and edit the files in `/var/lib/docker/`

Comment: Worked for an image made on a Debbie/Jessie Os.Thanks

Comment: one should also note that "no apt-update" usually means the apt command breaks, in case anyone is looking to "skip a step" and "save time" like I once did...

Comment: This just thought me how to install vim at the same time, use EXEC to get into the container. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just wanted to change one configuration from true to false in container. `apt-get` was not working due to permission issue inside container,so I tried `sed -i 's/texttobechanged/textwanted/g' filename` . It worked for me.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me the best option so i do not need to copy manually the file

Comment: @AmreeshTyagi good solution. my container is in kubernetes so I don't have root access. sed looks like the way to go. thx

Comment: Great answer. It worked for me in 2017 and I have ever since been referring many guys to this post https://blog.softwaremill.com/editing-files-in-a-docker-container-f36d76b9613c

Comment: heureka, finally a good answere! still worth gold in 2021, but a tipp: try with nano, never use vim, you can't close the editor anymore and have to restart the container unfortunately :_(

Comment: bash: apt-get: command not found is what I get after trying your solution

Comment: @AdarshBalu, sińce you have a different distro with different package manager.

Comment: Every container does not log you in as root by default. @yan's answer to login as root should be the right answer as the user asked for ability to edit files whatever may be the purpose..

Answer (score 713):

If you don't want to add an editor just to make a few small changes (e.g., change the Tomcat configuration), you can just use:

```
docker cp <container>:/path/to/file.ext .
```

which copies it to your local machine (to your current directory). Then edit the file locally using your favorite editor, and then do a

```
docker cp file.ext <container>:/path/to/file.ext
```

to replace the old file.

Comment: @Igor This should actuallly be the accepted solution as it is the proper way to do it without adding additional packages to your container, while adding packages should be a secondary solution.

Comment: For Windows platforms, you can use, for example: `docker cp <container>:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Web.config .` and `docker cp Web.config <container>:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Web.config`.

Comment: Nice workaround for the testing purpose! I don't recommend doing it in production.

Comment: And what do you recommend for production? Should people be editing files in a container interactively in production?

Comment: Worth noting this method changes the file ownership. It's possible but a bit fiddly to change it back afterwards by going into the container as root (`docker exec -u 0 -it mycontainer bash`) and then running a `chown` command.

Comment: Does not work for me with the nginx container. Command:

```docker cp nginx.conf f2:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf```

Error: ```Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): remove /nginx.conf: device or resource busy```

Comment: @lucid_dreamer i suggest using shellscript to change stuff, as you said it's in production, so you'd already have finished staging processes and know which lines you have to edit

Answer (score 174):

You can use `cat` if it's installed, which will most likely be the case if it's not a bare/raw container. It works in a pinch, and ok when copy+pasting to a proper editor locally.

```
cat > file
# 1. type in your content
# 2. leave a newline at end of file
# 3. ctrl-c / (better: ctrl-d)
cat file
```

`cat` will output each line on receiving a newline. Make sure to add a newline for that last line. ctrl-c sends a `SIGINT` for cat to exit gracefully. From the comments you see that you can also hit ctrl-d to denote end-of-file ("no more input coming").

Another option is something like `infilter` which injects a process into the container namespace with some ptrace magic: https://github.com/yadutaf/infilter

Comment: This is so incredibly useful if there are instillation permission issues!

Comment: `ctrl+D` is better than `ctrl+C`. `ctrl+D` sends an `EOF`. You do not need to add an extra newline at the end. With `ctrl+C`, if you forget to add the newline, you will lose the last line!

Comment: @wisbucky Nice! Even better. Might need to ctrl-d twice though.

Comment: One can also cat >> file to append instead of deleting the previous content.

Comment: Can I cancel the operation if I have already run `cat > file`?

Comment: Actually, this helped me a lot as I couldn't install any other depds

Comment: @egvo I'd suggest saving the output from the original file somewhere (locally or on remote) and they replace it back once you finish with your work. Once you edit a file with that command I believe you cannot restore it back.

Answer (score 66):

To keep your Docker images small, don't install unnecessary editors. You can edit the files over SSH from the Docker host to the container:

```
vim scp://remoteuser@containerip//path/to/document
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to leave this link which better explains the `vim scp://`  [vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim). Also, to get your container's IP address, you can use `sudo docker inspect <container_id> | grep "IPAddress"`

Comment: Just wondering, do I literally use "remoteuser", or "docker"? I've tried: `vim scp://docker@172.17.0.17//data/gitea/conf/app.ini` as well as `vim scp://remoteuser@172.17.0.17//data/gitea/conf/app.ini` and both of them just create a new, blank file.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein This requires configuring `ssh` on your docker container first. See https://blog.softwaremill.com/editing-files-in-a-docker-container-f36d76b9613c . But you generally don't want to be installing `ssh` in your container.

Answer (score 31):

You can use `cat` if installed, with the `>` caracter.
Here is the manipulation :

```
cat > file_to_edit
#1 Write or Paste you text
#2 don't forget to leave a blank line at the end of file
#3 Ctrl + C to apply configuration
```

Now you can see the result with the command

```
cat file
```

Comment: That should be the best answer. Simple, nice and clear!

Answer (score 27):

You can open existing file with

```
cat filename.extension
```

and copy all the existing text on clipboard.

Then delete old file with

```
rm filename.extension
```

or rename old file with

```
mv old-filename.extension new-filename.extension
```

Create new file with

```
cat > new-file.extension
```

Then paste all text copied on clipboard, press `Enter` and exit with save by pressing `ctrl+z`. And voila no need to install any kind of editors.

Comment: ctrl+z is likely to keep the file in a busy state. Better to use ctrl+c/ctrl+d at the end to save the file.

Answer (score 23):

For common edit operations I prefer to install `vi` (*vim-tiny*), which uses only **1491 kB** or `nano` which uses **1707 kB**.

In other hand `vim` uses **28.9 MB**.

We have to remember that in order for `apt-get install` to work, we have to do the `update` the first time, so:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim-tiny
```

To start the editor in *CLI* we need to enter `vi`.

Comment: For me this was the easier and faster solution, the above solutions could have the advantage of doesn't download apps but this is the easier one.

Answer (score 22):

Sometime you must first run the container with `root`:

```
docker exec -ti --user root <container-id> /bin/bash
```

Then in the container, to install Vim or something else:

```
apt-get install vim
```

Comment: this gives 'permission denied'

Answer (score 10):

I use "docker run" (not "docker exec"), and I'm in a restricted zone where we cannot install an editor. But I have an editor on the Docker host.

My workaround is: Bind mount a volume from the Docker host to the container (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/volume-shared-filesystems), and edit the file outside the container. It looks like this:

```
docker run -v /outside/dir:/container/dir
```

This is mostly for experimenting, and later I'd change the file when building the image.

Answer (score 9):

You can just edit your file on host and quickly copy it into and run it inside the container. Here is my one-line shortcut to copy and run a Python file:

```
docker cp main.py my-container:/data/scripts/ ; docker exec -it my-container python /data/scripts/main.py
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? - *"How do I edit files?"*

Answer (score 9):

After you shelled to the Docker container, just type:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nano
```

Answer (score 6):

See Stack Overflow question
*[sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place)*

It would be a good option here, if:

1. To modify a large file, it's impossible to use `cat`.
2. Install Vim is not allowed or takes too long.
   My situation is using the MySQL 5.7 image when I want to change the `my.cnf` file, there is no `vim`, `vi`, and Vim install takes too long (China Great Firewall). `sed` is provided in the image, and it's quite simple. My usage is like

   `sed -i /s/testtobechanged/textwanted/g filename`

   Use `man sed` or look for other tutorials for more complex usage.

Comment: Had to slightly modify it to ```sed -i 's/testtobechanged/textwanted/g' filename```
Worked perfect thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Windows container and you want change any file, you can get and use Vim in Powershell console easily.

To shelled to the Windows Docker container with PowerShell:

`docker exec -it <name> powershell`

- First install Chocolatey package manager

  `Invoke-WebRequest https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | Invoke-Expression;`
- Install Vim

  `choco install vim`
- Refresh ENVIRONMENTAL VARIABLE
  You can just `exit` and shell back to the container
- Go to file location and Vim it `vim file.txt`

Answer (score 4):

It is kind of screwy, but in a pinch you can use `sed` or `awk` to make small edits or remove text. Be careful with your regex targets of course and be aware that you're likely `root` on your container and might have to re-adjust permissions.

For example, removing a full line that contains text matching a regex:

```
awk '!/targetText/' file.txt > temp && mv temp file.txt
```

[(More)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413132/1812843)

Answer (score 4):

If you can only shell into container with bin/sh (in case bin/bash doesn't work)
and apt or apt-get doesn't work in the container, check whether apk is installed by entering apk in command prompt inside the container.
If yes, you can install nano as follows:
apk add nano

then nano will work as usual

Answer (score 3):

You can install nano

```
yum install nano
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to edit a few lines would be:

```
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main" > sources.list
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a mysql:8.0 container and found there was no text editor installed. There was also no package manager installed??? Luckily I had VS Code installed with the docker extension. With the docker extension you can view all running (and closed) containers and drill down into the file system, just as if it were a local file system.

HTH!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a special container which will contain only the command you need: Vim. I chose [python-vim](https://hub.docker.com/r/fedeg/python-vim/). It assumes that the data you want to edit are in a data container built with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie
ENV MY_USER_PASS my_user_pass
RUN groupadd --gid 1001 my_user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --home /home/my_user \
            -p $(echo "print crypt("${MY_USER_PASS:-password}", "salt")" | perl) \
            --uid 1001 --gid 1001 my_user
ADD src /home/my_user/src
RUN chown -R my_user:my_user /home/my_user/src
RUN chmod u+x /home/my_user/src
CMD ["true"]
```

You will be able to edit your data by mounting a Docker volume (src_volume) which will be shared by your data container (src_data) and the python-vim container.

```
docker volume create --name src_volume
docker build -t src_data .
docker run -d -v src_volume:/home/my_user/src --name src_data_1 src_data
docker run --rm -it -v src_volume:/src fedeg/python-vim:latest
```

That way, you do not change your containers. You just use a special container for this work.

Answer (score 0):

**First login as root :**
docker run -u root -ti  bash
**Type following commands:**
apt-get update &&
apt-get install nano

Comment: This essential command sequence is already present in several other answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update the container before trying to install the editor.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nano vi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view the file content in running container **without installing** anything

**Method 1**: if you are using vs code, then install a docker extension. Then when you run the container, click on docker icon on left side bar. It shows the directory structure of running container. you can drill down to your directory from gui, and open the file content.

**Method 2**: if you want to do it by command line, from powershell, run the command

**docker exec -it containerid sh**

then go to your directory using cd  where your file is.

then use the command "**more --lines 10 index.html**" (or your file name)

this will allow to view 10 lines at a time. pressing enter will display next 10 lines

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for small, try nano-tiny!

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nano-tiny
```

FWIW, the Postgres Docker Image was built with linuxkit.

For info and to compare...
My Container reports:

```
# apt-cache show nano-tiny
Package: nano-tiny
Source: nano
Version: 7.2-1
Installed-Size: 187
Maintainer: Jordi Mallach <jordi@debian.org>
```

```
# apt-cache show vim-tiny
Package: vim-tiny
Source: vim
Version: 2:9.0.1378-2
Installed-Size: 1689
Maintainer: Debian Vim Maintainers <team+vim@tracker.debian.org>
```

If you do not need VI editor features then maybe this version of nano is just right for you.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker Desktop, you can click on the container, view the files from the files tab, and right-click on any file to edit it!

Answer (score -2):

docker comes up with no editors. so simply install vim, 36MB space don't kill your docker!