# How to run vi on docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, vim, text-editor, vi

I have installed docker on my host virtual machine. And now want to create a file using `vi`.

But it's showing me an error:

```
bash: vi: command not found
```

Comment: vi may not be installed inside container. Which container have you installed and run?

Comment: You have to be more specific. Are you trying to run vi inside a container, if so which image is the container based on? In all likelihood you don't have vi installed. (apt-get install vim)

Comment: It depends on which `image` you are building from. Most probably `image` you are using is so lighter that it only has things you need to run as an image. You need to manually install packages you need.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing config inside a container. Do it in the Dockerfile instead.

Comment: are you using boot2docker? the host file system has probably been mapped onto your docker engine to allow you edit files from there rather than inside the docker engine vm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit file after I shell to a docker container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853247/how-to-edit-file-after-i-shell-to-a-docker-container)

Comment: It‘s the same like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853247/how-do-i-edit-a-file-after-i-shell-to-a-docker-container/43042406#43042406

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58267453/2568750

Comment: NOTE: I had a problem to update apt and install vim due unreachable name servers in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Therefore for me was crucial before to fix the setup: `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 287):

login into container with the following command:

```
docker exec -it <container> bash
```

Then , run the following command .

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim
```

Comment: Should you encounter permission denied issue while running apt-get, you need to run docker exec as root. "docker exec -u root -it <container> bash". Then apt-get should work.

Comment: Thanks @arunprakashpj. The only command that worked for image downloaded from AWS repository.

Comment: Thanks @Arun now vim command is working inside container

Comment: There are many docker images which aren't based on debian. `apt-get` won't work too well on an Alpine based image.

Answer (score 56):

The command to run depends on what base image you are using.

For Alpine, `vi` is installed as part of the base OS. Installing `vim` would be:

```
apk -U add vim
```

For Debian and Ubuntu:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
```

For CentOS, `vi` is usually installed with the base OS. For `vim`:

```
yum install -y vim
```

This should only be done in early development. Once you get a working container, the changes to files should be made to your image or configs stored outside of your container. Update your Dockerfile and other files it uses to build a new image. This certainly shouldn't be done in production since changes inside the container are by design ephemeral and will be lost when the container is replaced.

Comment: ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied

Comment: @garg10may commands need to be run as root. `USER root` inside the Dockerfile does this, but be sure to switch back to your other user. I'm a running container: `docker exec -u root ...`

Comment: great answer since it is most useful when being in container and not knowing what Linux is the container built upon

Answer (score 47):

**USE THIS:**

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
```

Explanation of the above command

1. **apt-get update** => Will update the current package
2. **apt-get install** => Will install the package
3. **-y** => Will by pass the permission, default permission will set to Yes.
4. **vim** => Name of the package you want to install.

Comment: I tried it but got this error `bash: apt-get: command not found`

Comment: @Junaid check with `apk add`

Answer (score 41):

Your container probably haven't installed it out of the box.

Run `apt-get install vim` in the terminal and you should be ready to go.

Comment: Yep, but I prefer `vim-tiny` (Ubuntu)

Comment: Before running 'apt-get install vim', you need to run 'apt-get update'.

Comment: First **`apt-get update`** THEN **`apt-get install vim`**

Comment: Before running `apt-get`, you should also check if apt-get is installed at all. Which won't be the case on CentOS or Alpine images.

Answer (score 19):

**error**:: `bash: vi: command not found`

run the below command by logging as root user to the container--

```
docker exec --user="root" -it (container ID) /bin/bash
apt-get update
apt-get install vim
```

Comment: --user="root" was indeed necessary in my case

Answer (score 15):

Add the following line in your Dockerfile then rebuild the docker image.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim
```

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, keep your docker images small by not installing unnecessary editors. You can edit the files over ssh from the docker host to the container:

```
vim scp://remoteuser@container-ip//path/to/document
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if the [container is running ssh](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/)? I thought it was a brilliant idea at first, but cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 12):

The most voted answer has the correct idea, however, it did not work in my case. The comment from [@java25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965844/java25) did the trick in my case. I had to log into the docker container as a `root` user to install vim. I am just posting the comment as an answer so that it is easier for others, having the similar problem, to find it.

```
docker exec -ti --user root <container-id> /bin/bash
```

Once you are inside docker, run the following commands now to install vi.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim
```

Answer (score 9):

Use below command in Debian based container:

```
apt-get install vim-tiny
```

Complete instruction for using in Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \   
 vim-tiny \  
 && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

It doesn't install unnecessary packages and removes unnecessary downloaded files, so your docker image size won't increase dramatically.

Answer (score 4):

To install within your Docker container you can run command

> docker exec  apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim

But this will be limited to the container in which vim is installed.
To make it available to all the containers, edit the Dockerfile and add

> RUN  apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim

or you can also extend the image in the new Dockerfile and add above command. Eg.

> FROM < image name >
>
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim

Answer (score 3):

Start a Docker container:

```
docker run -it <image_name> /bin/bash
```

Install Vim:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vim
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you look at the 14 existing answers, you'll notice that what you write has been posted before (with some variations). So your answer is unlikely to help anyone. Anyhow, thank you for writing an answer, keep it up!

Answer (score 2):

Inside container (in docker, not in VM), by default these are not installed.
Even **apt-get**, **wget** will not work. My VM is running on Ubuntu 17.10. For me **yum** package manager worked.

Yum is not part of Debian or ubuntu. It is part of red-hat. But, it works in Ubuntu and it is installed by default like apt-get

To install vim, use this command

```
yum install -y vim-enhanced
```

To uninstall vim :

```
yum uninstall -y vim-enhanced
```

Similarly,

```
yum install -y wget 
yum install -y sudo
```

-y is for assuming yes if prompted for any question asked after doing **yum install package-name**

Answer (score 2):

> error:: bash: vim: command not found

Run the below command by logging as root user to the container:

```
microdnf install -y vim
```

Comment: After wasting hours, I found your solution which solves my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want a small editor for simple housekeeping in a docker, use this in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y busybox && ln -s /bin/busybox /bin/vi
```

I used it on an Ubuntu 18 based docker.
(Of course you might need an `RUN apt-get update` before it but if you are making your own Docker file you probably already have that.)

Answer (score 0):

Usually changing a file in a docker container is not a good idea. Everyone will forget about the change after a while. A good way is to make another docker image from the original one.

Say in a docker image, you need to change a file named myFile.xml under /path/to/docker/image/. So, you need to do.

1. Copy myFile.xml in your local filesystem and make necessary changes.
2. Create a file named 'Dockerfile' with the following content-

```
FROM docker-repo:tag
ADD myFile.xml /path/to/docker/image/
```

Then build your own docker image with `docker build -t docker-repo:v-x.x.x .`

Then use your newly build docker image.