# How can I move transformation module to Memgraph that runs in Docker?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, memgraphdb

I'm trying to figure out how streaming with Kafka works in combination with Memgraph. I have a Memgraph running in a Docker container. I've created a module called `music.py` using Visual Studio Code but I can't save it into the docker.

```
import mgp
import json

@mgp.transformation
def rating(messages: mgp.Messages
                ) -> mgp.Record(query=str, parameters=mgp.Nullable[mgp.Map]):
    result_queries = []

    for i in range(messages.total_messages()):
        message = messages.message_at(i)
        movie_dict = json.loads(message.payload().decode('utf8'))
        result_queries.append(
            mgp.Record(
                query=("MERGE (u:User {id: $userId}) "
                        "MERGE (m:Album {id: $albumId, title: $title}) "
                        "WITH u, m "
                        "UNWIND $genres as genre "
                        "MERGE (m)-[:OF_GENRE]->(:Genre {name: genre}) "
                        "MERGE (u)-[r:RATED {rating: ToFloat($rating), timestamp: $timestamp}]->(m)"),
                parameters={
                    "userId": album_dict["userId"],
                    "albumId": album_dict["movie"]["movieId"],
                    "title": album_dict["album"]["title"],
                    "genres": album_dict["album"]["genres"],
                    "rating": album_dict["rating"],
                    "timestamp": album_dict["timestamp"]}))

    return result_queries
```

Should I run `vi` inside docker and copy/paste the code into it or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy your `music.py` file to the Docker container. Procedure for that is following:

1. Open command prompt/terminal and find out `CONTAINER ID` of Memgraph Docker container
2. Go to a folder/directory where `music.py` is saved and write the following command: `docker cp ./music.py <CONTAINER ID>:/usr/lib/memgraph/query_modules/music.py`

Don't forget to replace `<CONTAINER ID>` with real `CONTAINER ID` from step one. The `CONTAINER ID` looks something like `38cd0e84f17b`

You could also create file using `vi` if you have it installed in your container. I've never tried to do that, but take a look at [this question for instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515863/how-to-run-vi-on-docker-container) on how to do that.

For me personally the easiest way to create transformation module is using the Memgraph Lab, but you didn't mention if you have it or not.