# Unable to install vim or nano inside docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-14.04

Trying to install inside a docker, either vim or nano but I only get this:

```
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.152)]
```

Exit docker and do `ping archive.ubuntu.com` and I get reply, do the same time inside docker it does not respond.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How are you trying to install vim or nano?

Comment: I installed it with `apt-get install nano` and it worked. You might need to run `apt-get update` first.

Comment: @洋葱头 even `apt-get update` is not working the same 0%

Comment: I think the port is blocked

Comment: Basically your internet is not working in docker container?

Comment: Did you expose ports in your `Dockerfile`? But I think apt-get uses port `80`. And I didn't expose that port either ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit a file after I shell to a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853247/how-do-i-edit-a-file-after-i-shell-to-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to run docker with:

```
docker run --net=host
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 130):

First I create the docker:

```
sudo docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Instead of this you can enter in a running docker with his number or name:

```
sudo docker exec -it be8aa338d656 bash
```

Then inside the docker run this code:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim nano
```

Comment: Stuck here:

`gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com`

Comment: once I have a similar problem. I update docker to the last version and it solve everything. I have Docker version 1.11.1

Comment: I had problems trying to access path outside network of the of the docker, but updating solve my problem

Comment: I am using `Docker version 1.11.1, build 5604cbe`

Comment: :p then I don't know, sorry

Comment: I believe it's the first "apt-get update" what people is missing. Once done you'll be able to install nano

Answer (score 18):

Here is how you can use `wget` to fetch and install `nano` and then use it in to edit a file in the `python:latest` docker image.

```
cd ~

wget http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.4/nano-2.4.2.tar.gz

tar -xzf nano-2.4.2.tar.gz

cd nano-2.4.2

 ./configure

make

make install  # removed sudo from this line
```

Now test it:

```
touch file

nano file

# close with `ctrl+z enter`
rm file # delete that test file
```

---

**UPDATE:**
`apt-get` worked for me... I bet other people weren't running update first.

```
apt-get update

apt-get install nano
```

Comment: there is also no "bash: make: command not found"

Comment: I  get: `configure: error: in /root/nano-2.4.2: configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`

Comment: apt-get update solved "E: Unable to locate package nano".

Answer (score 8):

Question is very old but if anyone looking for the solution, here's how I have solved it, in my Dockerfile I have written this :

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install vim nano
```

-y gives automatic yes to continue the command. Works like a charm!

Comment: must run update code other wise show unable to locate.this answer usefull

Answer (score 3):

In my case the container only recognize the package manager **yum**

So, I enter as root

```
docker exec -u root -ti e826db00b37c /bin/bash
```

And then install:

```
yum install nano 
yum install vim
```

Answer (score 3):

To install **vi**, first make sure **apt-get** is updated:

```
docker exec <container-name> apt-get update
```

Then do:

```
docker exec <container-name> apt-get install vi
```

For **nano** do:

```
docker exec <container-name> apt-get install nano
```

If you are looking for the container name do:

```
docker ps
```

Answer (score 2):

Some customized docker images have just the bare minimum dependencies to run. This sometimes means that even `apt` package manager is not be installed by default and recreating another docker image from scratch is not an option.

But, I realized that most docker images come preinstalled with `yum` package manager.

So you can install vim or nano using;

```
yum install vim
```

or

```
yum install nano
```

Comment: `yum not found` in the `python:latest` container

Answer (score 2):

For mac users.
First, enter into your container environment

```
$ docker exec -it your-container /bin/sh
```

Then update apt package manager and install what you want  :

```
$ apt update
$ apt install vim/nano
```

Then accept the prompt confirmation: y
Then good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your docker is unable to connect to internet. Try this:-

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then restart:-

```
service docker restart
```

If still not working, read here:-
[My docker container has no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet)

Comment: Getting this error:

```root@appscale2:~# sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 -
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
sysctl: "-" must be of the form name=value```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Sorry there's a typo, you need to skip that "-" at the last. I have edited my ans.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no luck at all with apt or apt-get.  The docker I am using from someone else doesn't seem to have the /etc/apt sources configured correct (or disabled).  I need to edit the configurations.

Luckily dpkg and curl are available inside the container. I used the binaries for my amd64. 
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vim/2:7.4.712-2ubuntu4

mkdir /tmp/vim
cd /tmp/vim

curl http://launchpadlibrarian.net/221875822/vim_7.4.712-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb > vim.deb
curl http://launchpadlibrarian.net/221873815/vim-common_7.4.712-2ubuntu4_arm64.deb > vim-common.deb
curl http://launchpadlibrarian.net/221875814/vim-runtime_7.4.712-2ubuntu4_all.deb > vim-runtime.deb
curl https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/vim/2:7.4.712-2ubuntu4 > vim.deb
curl http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gpm/libgpm2_1.20.4-6.1_amd64.deb > libgpm2.deb

dpkg -i *.deb

It's not the best solution, but at least now I can edit the configuration files.