# Editing Files inside of a Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

How can I edit the config files that are inside of a docker container that has been downloaded on the host?

I am using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-traefik-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-docker-containers-on-ubuntu-16-04) but I am not sure where to find and edit the traefik.toml file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I edit a file after I shell to a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853247/how-do-i-edit-a-file-after-i-shell-to-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 50):

There are multiple ways to achieve that:

You can enter the container by running the command:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash
```

Note however depending on the container you may not have a simple text editor..

---

Another alternative would be to copy the file you want to edit from the container onto your host by running:

```
docker cp <container-name>:/path/to/file/in/container .
```

Edit the file and then copy it back into the container:

```
docker cp <file> <container-name>:/path/to/file/in/container
```

---

There's also a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/) which will mount a host folder into the container

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/files:/dir/containing/file/in/container ...
```

Files created in that folder in the container *after* the mount will be visible on the host **BUT** if that folder already existed in the container *before* the mount, it will be shadowed by the host folder making it inaccessible to either host or container.

Comment: You have my upvote, but it's important to note, option 1 does not work on a traefik container, which is in question. example, you're not even able to do `docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/sh` which gives you the default shell of the container. I'm slightly convinced (though unable to fully explain) that it doesn't have any shells you can execute to do any form of `docker exec -it`

Comment: You are probably right. The traefik image is based on scratch

Comment: The third option binds a folder from the host into the container, not the other way around.

Comment: @Tamlyn Good point! I used 3rd option thinking it's for binding from container to host and was wondering why it's not working. I think yamenk should edit their answer

Comment: In option two, when you pull files out of docker container, what is . and where do I find the files on the Windows file system?

Answer (score 10):

I was running into the same issue and found a nice way to handle this. Using VS Code and the docker extension, get the container running. In the list of Containers, right click on the one you want to edit. Choose: Attach Visual Studio Code.

[image: Attach VS Code to Docker]

Another VS Code instance should open up that is directly attached to the container. Click on the Open Folder and navigate to the file you wish to edit. Pour a nice stout, chill for a moment, then get back to coding. :)

[image: VS Code attached to Docker]

Comment: does this work on windows containers? getting username/pwd error.

Comment: The documentation of this VS Code feature is [available here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container) btw. Your extensions don't carry over though, requiring their installation inside the container.

Comment: note that you need to install VS code extension Remote - Containers https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers

Comment: You will not see the option to "Attach Visual Studio Code" without installing Remote - Containers extension as stated in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, works perfect with Windows containers too.

1. Run a cmd into a crashing container to prevent exit:

   docker run -dit docker/image cmd
2. Start VS Code with the docker extension. There is a open and download option for each file, very nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the container over port 22 and then edit whatever file you want over ssh.

```
vim scp://user@myserver[:port]//path/to/file.txt
```

See more: [How to edit file within Docker container or edit a file after I shell into a Docker container?](https://jhooq.com/docker-edit-file-inside-container/#6-install-vim-editor-along-with-dockerfile)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a line to a file such as a line of config you can use echo like this and append it to a file:

```
echo 'super-setting: "10.96.85.221:9200"' >> config.yml
```

This only works if you want to add extra lines and not if you want to edit an existing line.

I've found it a quick and easy way to make and test temp changes to a file in a docker container.