# How to edit file inside a docker container into amazon web services server?

Tags: docker, vim, amazon-ec2, docker-container, nano

I installed docker with my required files but now I need to edit and save into docker I tried with nano but unfortunately unable to install and also I tried with vim but it does not work.

So i searched for it finally I founded it 
([How to edit file after I shell to a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853247/how-to-edit-file-after-i-shell-to-a-docker-container)) in this question, the 2nd answer is an easy way to edit but I don't know how to copy files from the live server(aws) into local.

Please help me how to do this. thanks in advance...!

Comment: If you `ssh` into the AWS instance, you can use `scp` to copy files to and from it.

Comment: i dont know how to copy using scp where will i find scp?? im a beginner for aws and docker so only i struggling a lot

Comment: As a beginner, please give more context in your questions. I assume your local system runs Windows (as Linux usually has both `ssh` and `scp`). There's `pscp` if you use PuTTY, or just install [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php); that's a proper tool for noobs :-)

Comment: yes offcourse my local system is windows i'm using putty now.WinSCP is a good one ...anyway thank you for your response...!

Comment: but i tried with winscp using hostname and proper credintials.it connected into server but nothing displays (i mean there is no folders or files) but in my aws server i installed docker and some contents please help me how to do this?

Comment: Sorry, but this kind of troubleshooting is just not possible, with this little information and in a chat. Can't you ask an onsite colleague to give you a helping hand?! You seem to be trying to do things that are way over your head.

Comment: please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host) it will helpful for you