# Unable to find Jenkins config files inside docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerhub

I have used Jenkins docker image from dockerhub(https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker)

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root
ENV http_proxy http://bc-proxy-vip.de.pri.o2.com:8080
ENV https_proxy http://bc-proxy-vip.de.pri.o2.com:8080
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ldap-utils curl wget vim nano sudo
RUN adduser jenkins sudo
User jenkins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 50000
```

The docker build command was executed successfully and container also started successfully.

Docker build command :

```
docker build --no-cache -t myjenkins .
```

Docker container command :

```
docker run --net=host --name=my_jenkins -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 myjenkins
```

Then I logged in to the container via `docker run -it myjenkins bash`. I'm unable to find jenkins config files like config.xml, jenkins.xml etc.

Comment: if you want to get inside of a container you need to use `docker exec -it my_jenkins bash` not run, as with run you're starting new container.

Comment: thanks :) It worked

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old issue, but I ran into this recently myself and found that when you run the containerized version of Jenkins, the configuration files are stored in:

/var/jenkins_home

A lot of people seem to be suggesting they're in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins for other Jenkins installs.

Comment: This answer is correct. And you might run into missing editors so you want to check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853247/how-do-i-edit-a-file-after-i-shell-to-a-docker-container

Comment: In the more recent containerized Jenkins releases (v2.375.5) , these files are indeed stored under `/var/jenkins_home` , another alternative method to is to use the variable `${JENKINS_HOME}` which as it new suggests contains the locations of all Jenkins files