# Convert Neo4j-Database-Dump Into CSV-File Without Neo4j-Enterprise-Server

Tags: neo4j, export-to-csv, graph-databases, dump

How are you supposed to convert Neo4j-Database-Dumps into CSV-Files?

I've created a [Neo4j-Docker-container](https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j) 
Which is created from [Neo4j Community Edition (5.6.0)](https://neo4j.com/download-center/#community). 
Read the [Neo4j-Docs's Export-to-CSV](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/export/csv/). 
Got a Neo4j-Database-Dump from [ICIJ's Offshore-Leaks-Database](https://offshoreleaks.icij.org/pages/database) 
On their [GitHub OffshoreLeaks-Data-Packages](https://github.com/ICIJ/offshoreleaks-data-packages/blob/eabbabfeaf1983c2b83c11125802fcdeda92d9ac/data/icij-offshoreleaks-44.dump). 
Imported on the Neo4j-Docker-container's Neo4j-Community-Server.

I'm looking for ways to export without needing to sign-up or purchase Neo4j. 
I just want the data to be importable to other databases and services. 
What are some ways you've come up with exporting the data?

I cannot export the database as-is, because 
[Neo4j only allows 1 User-Database for Community-Edition-Installations](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/manage-databases/introduction/). 
So [their docs on Export-2-CSV](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/export/csv/) don't work as-is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've gotten this to work is this.

Steps:

1. Get [Graph Database Data](https://github.com/ICIJ/offshoreleaks-data-packages/blob/eabbabfeaf1983c2b83c11125802fcdeda92d9ac/data/icij-offshoreleaks-44.dump)
2. [Rename to dump extension as needed](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/planning/)
3. [Create Neo4j-Docker-Container](https://hub.docker.com/_/neo4j)

   ```bash
    docker run -d \
       -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 \
       -e apoc.export.file.enabled=true \
       -e apoc.import.file.enabled=true \
       -e apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=true \
       -e NEO4J_PLUGINS=\[\"apoc\"\] \
       neo4j
   ```
4. Create the Neo4j-Dumps Directory

   1. [`winpty docker exec -it [neo4j_container] sh`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)
   2. `mkdir /var/lib/neo4j/data/dumps`
5. [Import Data into Neo4j-Container](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-backup/)

   ```bash
   docker cp [filename] [neo4j-container]:/var/lib/neo4j/data/dumps/
   ```
6. Create an `apoc.conf` that allows Neo4j-Dumps

   1. [`winpty docker exec -it [neo4j_container] sh`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)
   2. Create `apoc.conf`

      - `touch /var/lib/neo4j/conf/apoc.conf`
   3. Add/Edit `apoc.conf`

      - [CLI Editor Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30853247/how-do-i-edit-a-file-after-i-shell-to-a-docker-container)
      - [Docker UI File-Editor > Files > Edit (Right-click)](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/use-desktop/container/)

      ```
      apoc.export.file.enabled=true
      apoc.import.file.enabled=true
      apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=true
      dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
      ```

      - Needed if commands not working
   4. Restart Neo4j-Container to take affect
7. [Restore Database Dump](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-dump/)

   ```bash
   bin/neo4j-admin database load [filename (no extension)] --overwrite-destination
   ```
8. [Migrate Database Dump to Neo4j v5.X.X](https://neo4j.com/docs/upgrade-migration-guide/current/version-5/)

   ```bash
   bin/neo4j-admin database migrate [filename (no extension)] --force-btree-indexes-to-range
   ```
9. Reassign the single User-Database that Neo4j allows

   1. Edit `neo4j.conf`
   2. Add / Uncomment-Edit

      - The filename decides the database name

      ```
      initial.dbms.default_database=[filename (no extension)]
      ```
   3. Restart Neo4j-Container to take affect
10. Rename the Neo4j-Dump file as `neo4j.dump`

    - This is because only the Neo4j-Database is allowed APOC commands
    - Either edit the filename or readd
11. [Restore Database Dump](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-dump/)

    ```bash
    bin/neo4j-admin database load neo4j --overwrite-destination
    ```
12. [Migrate Database Dump to Neo4j v5.X.X](https://neo4j.com/docs/upgrade-migration-guide/current/version-5/)

    ```bash
    bin/neo4j-admin database migrate neo4j --force-btree-indexes-to-range
    ```
13. Reassign the single User-Database that Neo4j allows

    1. Edit `neo4j.conf`
    2. Add / Uncomment-Edit

       ```
       initial.dbms.default_database=neo4j
       ```
    3. Restart Neo4j-Container to take affect
14. Restore Database Dump

    ```
    CALL apoc.export.csv.all("filename.csv", {})
    ```

    1. Use the Neo4j Studio (Website)
    2. Use Command-Line

       1. [Shell into the Neo4j-Container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)
       2. `/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j` command
15. Save `neo4j.csv` from `/var/lib/neo4j/import/neo4j.csv`