# How to save SED result in target file?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, find

I want to insert specific line (XXX) in specific place (new line after b) in example.txt. When I do:

```
$ sed '/b/a XXX' example.txt
a
b
XXX
c
```

It seems to work, but the original remains file unchanged.

```
$ cat example.txt 
a
b
c
```

How to change example.txt by SED permanently ?

Comment: use -i flag ( in-place ). the default substitutions are directed only to stdout ( so things are rerunnable )

Comment: It's worth mentioning that even though OP specified `linux` as his platform it doesn't imply that his `sed` version supports `-i`. It's not specified in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sed.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12696125/1030675

Comment: @choroba that works too - happy to un-hammer if you think it's more appropriate

Comment: @TomFenech: Never mind, these two are almost duplicates, too :)