# How to set learning rate in a big net for fine-tuning in Caffe?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a big net with many layers. I add a new full-connected layer in the net and want to do a fine-tuning. However, it's so difficult to set `lr_mult: 0` in every layer except the new one, since there are many layers in the net.
If there is a good way to solve these problem?

Thanks.

Comment: try [`sed`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12696224/1714410)

Comment: Sorry, could you give me some details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about, instead of setting `lr_mult: 0` for all parameters to all layers prior to the new fully connected layer, just stop the back propagation after the new layer?

You can do that by setting [`propagate_down: false`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L333).
For example:

```
layer {
  name: "new_layer"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  ...
  inner_product_param {
    ...
  }
  propagate_down: false # do not continue backprop after this layer
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), a command line utility, to directly change all entries in your prototxt file:

```
~$ sed -i -E 's/lr_mult *: *[0-9]+/lr_mult: 0/g' train_val.prototxt
```

This one line will change all `lr_mult` in your `train_val.prototxt` to zero. You'll only need to *manually* set the `lr_mult` for the new layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I Think `sed` may be more proper for me. By the way, I have another question that is If the layer designed by me has two bottom and I want only one of them can back propagation, how shoud I design the layer and set net.prototxt? Thanks.

Comment: @nannanmath please post as new question