# sed outputs correct change on console but doesn't edit in file

Tags: sed, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to edit my file using this sed command

```
sudo sed "s/192[^:]\+ /192.168.56.109/" file
```

The command outputs the complete file with correct change, but doesn't edit the file. If I open the file it is same as before.

Comment: you need either the `-i` option for inplace edit (see the man page) or you have to pipe output into a temp file and move temp file in a second step.

Comment: -i is not working. I tried it like, >`sudo sed -i "s/192[^:]\+ /192.168.56.109/" file`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed edit the file in place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-the-file-in-place)

Answer (score 0):

if inplace `-i` option is not working you can do this

```
sed "s/192[^:]\+ /192.168.56.109/" file > temp && mv temp file
```

make sure you have a backup though.

Comment: Can't it work without this overhead of moving data in different files?

Comment: `mv` doesn't move data, just the file handle.

Comment: Well! I tried >`sudo sed -i 's/192[^:]\+ /192.168.56.109/' file`, with single quotes instead of >`sudo sed -i "s/192[^:]\+ /192.168.56.109/" file` and this worked for me... thanks :)