# Append a word for matching text

Tags: linux, shell

I have file test.txt and file contains some lines
So i have to add "done" at the end of the word once the verification is done, 
Initial text file

### test.txt

abc

bcd

cde

expected output

### test.txt

abc DONE

bcd DONE

cde DONE

Below is the code i am using

```
 k=0
 for i in `cat test.txt` 
 do 
 if [[ $k -le 5 ]];
 then
 echo $i >> XYZ
 k=`expr $k + 1`
 sed  '/$i/a "DONE"' test.txt
 fi;
 done
```

But i couldn't see any changes in test.txt. Any idea how to do

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799789/expansion-of-variable-inside-single-quotes-in-a-command-in-bash-shell-script) for dealing with expansions within single quotes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place) for `sed` in-place replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two major flaws; bash variables are preserved literally within single quotes and you did not use *sed*'s in-place replacement `-i` flag.

```
#!/bin/bash
k=0
for i in `cat test.txt`
do
        if [[ $k -le 5 ]];
        then
                echo "$i" >> XYZ
                k=`expr $k + 1`
                sed -i 's/'"$i"'/'"$i"' DONE/' test.txt
        fi;
done
```

Be careful when editing files simultaneously while reading through them.