# How to insert a new line between 2 specific characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there anyway to insert new lines in-between 2 specific sets of characters?
I want to insert a new line every time `}{` occurs in a text file, however I want this new line to be inserted between the 2 curly brackets.
For example `}\n{`

Comment: Preferably within a file but either in the file or STDOUT is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run

> sed -i -e 's/}{/}\n{/g' filename.ext

where

- `sed` is your stream editor program
- `-i` is the option to [edit file `filename.ext` in place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696224/1312080)
- `-e` means that a regular expression follows
- `s/}{/}\n{/g` is the regular expression meaning find all (`g`) instances of **}{** in every line and replace them with **}\n{** where `\n` is the regex for new line. If you omit `g`, it will only replace the first occurrence of the search pattern but still in every line.

To test before committing changes to your file, omit the `-i` option and it will print the result in STDOUT.

**Example:**

Create file:

```
echo "First }{ Last" > repltest.txt
```

Run

```
sed -e 's/}{/}\n{/g' repltest.txt
```

Prints the following to STDOUT:

```
First }
{ Last
```

To effect the change in the same file, use `-i` option.

To run this against STDIN instead of a file, omit `-i` and the filename in the piped command after something that outputs STDIN, for example:

```
cat repltest.txt | sed -e 's/}{/}\n{/g'
```

which does the same as `sed -e 's/}{/}\n{/g' repltest.txt`

Comment: Did not work for me on OS X and bash 5.0.2 (it inserted an "n")

Comment: Best help ever. Used it for Amazon Access Logs in S3 from API Gateway. I added an extra `\n` so its easier to read and grep from there. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `sed`.

```
sed [-i] -e 's/}{/}\n{/g' file.txt
```

Every instance of `}{` will be replaced with `}\n{`. You can use the `-i` flag if you want to replace the text in the file.