# Add a line in a specific position with Linux and output to the same file?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

How to add a third line in file.txt:

```
             line 1
             line 2
             line 4
```

sed could do with `sed '3iline 3' file.txt` but I want to output to the same file.
I tried `sed '3iline 3' file.txt >> file.txt` which didn't work. It did add the line but it duplicates file.txt, I got this:

```
       line 1
       line 2
       line 4
       line 1
       line 2
       line 3
       line 4
```

Comment: Only some implementations of `sed` (GNU sed and BSD sed AFAIK) support `-i` switch for "in-place" editing.

Comment: You can also play around with diamond `<>` operator in `Bash` if you feel brave: http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39143992/3691891

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to do this is to write to a second file, then replace the original. You can only *append* to an arbitrary file; you cannot insert into the middle of one.

```
t=$(mktemp)
sed '3iline 3' file.txt > "$t" && mv "$t" file.txt
```

If your version of `sed` supports it, you can use the `-i` option to automate the handling of the temporary file.

```
sed -i '3iline 3' file.txt  # GNU
sed -i "" '3iline 3 ' file.txt  # BSD sed requires an argument for -i
```