# sed to add quotes around timestamps

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a large file that contains timestamps in the following format:

```
2018-08-22T13:06:04.442774Z
```

I would like to add double quotes around all the occurrences that match this specific expression. I am trying to use sed, but I don't seem to be able to find the right command. I am trying something around these lines:

```
sed -e s/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}.[0-9]\{6\}Z/"$0"/g my_file.json
```

and I am pretty sure that the problem is around my "replace" expression.

How should I correct the command?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show an excerpt of that file?

Comment: Try `sed -i` instead of `-e`

Comment: @GillesQuenot he was not parsing json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the `sed` replacement command with single quotes and use `&` instead of `$0` in the RHS to replace with the whole match:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{6\}Z/"&"/g' file > outfile
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/FMUE20315)

Also, do not forget to escape the `.` char if you want to match a dot, and not any character.

You may also remove excessive escapes if you use ERE syntax:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6}Z/"&"/g'
```

If you want to [change the file inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place), use the `-i` option,

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{6\}Z/"&"/g' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice and easy!

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}T[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{6\}Z\)/"\1"/g' my_file.json
```

multiple modifications:

- wrap command in single quotes
- use `\(` and `\)` to create a group (referenced by '\1` in the replacement section)
- escape the '.' and '{' and '}' characters