# How can I append spaces to the end of specific lines using regex

Tags: regex, unix, sed, hp-ux

I have a text file that has lines of different lengths. I need to make these uniform so that the PLSQL Developers text import function reads them correctly. Lines that are 89 characters long need to be padded with 4 spaces on the end. For some reason the -i argument to sed isn't accepted either.

The file can be found [here](https://www.vocalink.com/media/3062/valacdos.txt)

I have tried a number of different regex commands found from various sources through Google but none of them are working, either because the 'function cannot be parsed' or it doesn't add the spaces needed.

The code that I wrote that worked using Notepad++ was 
Find: (^.{89})($) 
Replace: \1    \2

I've tried a number of unix sed commands such as 
    `sed -e "s/(^.{89})($)/\1   \2/" file.txt`
    `sed -e "s/(^.{89})($)/\1\s\s\s\s\2/" file.txt`
`sed -e "s/(^.{89})($)/\1\ \ \ \ \2/" file.txt`
`sed -e "s/\(^.\{89\}\)\($\)/\1\ \ \ \ \2" file.txt`
`sed -e 's/\(^.\{89\}\)\($\)/\1[[:space:]]\2/g' file.txt`
`sed -e 's/\(^.\{89\}\)\($\)/\1[[:space:]]\{4\}\2/g' file.txt`
`sed -e 's/(^.{89})($)/\1[[:space:]]{4}\2/g' file.txt`

Comment: Are you on Mac OS? Try `sed -i '' 's/^.\{89\}$/&   /' file.txt` (with 4 spaces after `&`). In POSIX BRE patterns, `{m,n}` quantifier must have escaped braces. If `-i` still does not work, use `sed 's/^.\{89\}$/& /' file.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: Better put some sample text ere.

Comment: What do you mean that the `-i` option "isn't accepted"? Don't include end of line `$` as a capture group with `($)`. It's unnecessary and won't work. Did you try `sed -e "s/(^.{89})$/\1  
  /" file.txt`?

Comment: @lurker passing in -i to sed I get "sed: illegal option -- i". I've just tried your command and got the "cannot be parsed" error.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit hasty in my suggest. Try this: `sed -e "s/([^.]{89})$/\1 /" file.txt`

Comment: @lurker Some success. That command, including escapes for the ( ) { } characters added spaces, but removed line ends. I tried adding them back in with ```sed -e "s/\([^.]\{89\}\)\($\)/\1    \2/"``` but no joy.

Comment: The behavior of `sed` on your system isn't the same as Linux. It shouldn't remove a line end. The `$` is a token representing the end of line but shouldn't have to be resubstituted in the replacement. If my suggestion worked but removed line ends, you can put the line end back, possibly, with `sed -e "s/([^.]{89})$/\1 \n/`. Also check the `sed` options in the `sed` manual page (`man sed`) for line end handling.

Comment: I'm finding more articles where people are having issues with sed in HP-UX. using the new line \n just adds 'n' where the end of line should be, which is ridiculously frustrating. I'll keep trying different combinations of the command.

Comment: That behavior of `\n` is what I feared. You could check the `sed` options as there may be an option that causes it to see it as a line-end. I still find it odd that it gobbles up the line end if you use `$` on the source regex. I suppose another option might be `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you are using BRE POSIX syntax and unescaped `(` / `)` are treated as literal parentheses and unescaped `{`/`}` are treated as literal braces.

This should work:

```
sed 's/^.\{89\}$/&    /' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Here:

- `^` - matches the start of a line
- `.\{89\}` - matches any 89 chars
- `$` - asserts the end of line position.

The `&` in the replacement refers to the whole match.

If you need to use `-i` option, see [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place).

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor but this just output the same text file with no additional spaces added to the lines.

Comment: @PaulWright What is your `sed` version? OS? Look, [the `sed` command is working](https://ideone.com/kzqnYL).

Comment: OS appears to be  HP-UX 11i Version 3 Feb 2007. The -V command is't working to show me the version of sed.

Comment: @PaulWright I can't find any details about it. I wonder if `&` is supported. Try `sed 's/^\(.\{89\}\)$/\1    /' file.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: Same result I'm afraid. I don't think there is going to be an easy solution on HP-UX.

Comment: @PaulWright I have seen such environments where `{m}`  quantifier is just not supported. Can you please try `echo "1234567890" | sed 's/^..........$/<s>&    <e>/'` and confirm if it works?

Comment: Looks like it added one space to the end of the string. I need to type out 89 .'s to get it to work then?

Comment: @PaulWright Well, I am afraid it might be the only way out.

Comment: I've just tried this with the file. It works until I use the end of line character. Then it doesn't seem to find a match?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '{ <br>
 diff = 89 - length($0); <br>
 for(i=1;i<=diff; i++) <br>
 { <br>
   $0 = $0  "a" <br>
 } <br>
 print $0 <br>
} <br>
' FileName.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A software tools kludge for HP-UX, based on [its manuals](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux):

```
sed 's/.*/    /' file | paste -d ' ' file - | cut -c 1-93
```

How it works:

1. Use `sed` to create a dummy stream of the same number of lines as *file*, but with four spaces on each line.
2. Use `paste` to append the dummy stream to what's in *file*.  (Because of the `-d ' '` it adds *five* spaces, but it doesn't much matter.)
3. Use `cut` to chop off anything over *93* bytes.

If *HP-UX* `sed` is even less like *GNU* `sed` than I've supposed, it could be replaced with some equivalent like:

```
yes '    ' | head -n $(wc -l < file) | paste -d ' ' file - | cut -c 1-93
```