# I need delete two " " with sed command

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to delete `""` in file

```
"CITFFUSKD-E0"
```

I have tried `sed 's/\"//`.

Result is:

```
CITFFUSKD-E0"
```

How I can delete both ?

Also I need to delete everything behind first word but input can be this one:

```
"CITFFUSKD-E0"
"CITFFUSKD_E0"
"CITFFUSKD E0"
```

Result I want it:

```
CITFFUSKD
```

Comment: Use `sed 's/"//g'`, and probably `sed 's/[^[:alnum:]].*//'` to get the first word. So, try `sed 's/"//g' file | sed 's/[^[:alnum:]].*//' > newfile`

Comment: Glad it did, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56374900/3832970) below.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
sed 's/"//g' file | sed 's/[^[:alnum:]].*//' > newfile
```

Or, contract the two `sed` commands into one `sed` call [as @Wiimm suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56374737/i-need-delete-two-with-sed-command/56374900?noredirect=1#comment99353330_56374900):

```
sed 's/"//g;s/[^[:alnum:]].*//' file > newfile
```

If you want to replace inline, see [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125).

*Explanation*:

- `sed 's/"//g' file` - removes all `"` chars from the file
- `sed 's/[^[:alnum:]].*//' > newfile` - also removes all chars from a line starting from the first non-alphanumeric char and saves the result into a `newfile`.

Comment: shorter version of `sed 's/"//g' file | sed 's/[^[:alnum:]].*//' > newfile`: `sed 's/"//g; s/[^[:alnum:]].*//' file > newfile`

Comment: @Wiimm Right, I always focus on the immediate problem when it comes to sed and forget about possible enhancements like this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z]*/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]+/,"",val);print val}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

> delete everything behind first word

```
sed 's/^"\([[:alpha:]]*\)[^[:alpha:]]*.*/\1/'
```

Match the first `"`. Then match a sequence of alphabetic characters. Match until you find non-alphabetic character `^[:alpha:]`. Then match the rest. Substitute it all for `\1` - it is a backreference for the part inside `\( ... \)`, ie. the first word.

> I need delete two “ ” with sed command

Remove all possible `"`:

```
sed 's/"//g'
```

Extract the string between `"`:

```
sed 's/"\([^"]*\)"/\1/'
```

Remove everything except alphanumeric characters (numbers + a-z + a-Z, ie. `[0-9a-zA-z]`):

```
sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do all in one go, remove the `"`, print the first part:

```
awk -F\" '{split($2,a,"-| |_");print a[1]}' file
CITFFUSKD
CITFFUSKD
CITFFUSKD
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have 1 line, you can use

```
grep -Eo "(\w)*" file | head -1
```

For normal files (starting with a double quote on each line)
, try this

```
tr -c [^[:alnum:]] '"' < file | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Many legitimate ways to solve this.

I favor using what you know about your data to simplify solutions -- this is usually an option. If everything in your file follows the same pattern, you can simply extract the first set of capitalized letters encountered:

```
sed 's/"\([A-Z]\+\).*$/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

awk '{gsub(/^.|....$/,"")}NR==1' file

CITFFUSKD