# How to replace string into numbers using sed?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I am trying to replace string into number from the file
So, I have variable &FLOW which need to change to 001, ex :

```
cat file.txt
This is file ' PISP &FLOW'
PISD.DATA.CYCLE&FLOW..ONE
```

desired output

```
This is file ' PISP 001'
PISD.DATA.CYCLE001.ONE
```

I tried below commands in a script :

```
for item in file.txt
do
sed 's/\&FLOW/\./001/g' $item
sed 's/\&FLOW/001/g' $item
done
```

It is giving error. The second sed command is working, but I need to run first the beginning sed command otherwise after running first the second sed command, it would ignore the beginning sed command.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the first command supposed to do?

Comment: You set `item` to to literal string `filename`, but the file you show as example input is called `file.txt`, so that won't work, for starters.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I changed into file.txt. It is still not working

Comment: @JNevill it supposed to change from two dots into one after variable

Comment: First of all, you do not need to use two `sed` commands, you may chain them like `sed 's/1/2/g;s/3/4/g'`. However, your patterns are so similar, they only differ in 1 char, so you may make it optional and use a single pattern. More importantly, you did not actually modify file contents, you need to pass the `-i` (inline) option. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56385601/3832970) with explanations of the pattern and how to use `-i` with both Linux (GNU) and Mac OS (FreeBSD) `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single `sed` command and use `-i` to actually modify the file contents and you need to pass `file.txt` as the input for the `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/&FLOW\.\{0,1\}/001/g' file.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/6h94bc). If you are using it in Mac OS, you need `sed -i '' 's/&FLOW\.\{0,1\}/001/g' file.txt`. Also see [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125).

**Pattern details**

It is a POSIX BRE compliant pattern matching

- `&FLOW` - a literal `&FLOW` substring
- `\.\{0,1\}` - 0 or 1 occurrence of a `.` char.

Comment: @flow If you have any related questions, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for item in file.txt
do
  sed 's/\&FLOW\./001/g' $item
  sed 's/\&FLOW/001/g' $item
done
```

You had a redundant `/` in after `FLOW`

This might also work:

```
  sed -i 's/\&FLOW[\.]?/001/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for response! I have a question, what ? is for?

Comment: `?` is a conditional match for 0 or 1 occurrence of `.` character. If this is correct answer, please mark it as such.

Comment: `?` is an ERE metachar, it won't work in sed (which uses BREs) unless you add `-E` to enable EREs (GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed which you're probably using for `-i` anyway). Or you can use the POSIX BRE equivalent of `\{0,1\}`.