# shell html tag remove duplicates

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I need to clean the unnecessary Italics tags in HTML, in any case :)

here my code:

```
text <i>text</i> <i>text text</i> text
text <i>text</i><i> text text</i> text
text<i>text </i>text text<i>text text</i> text
text <i>text</i><i></i> text text<i>text text</i> text
```

here the result I expect:

```
text <i>text text text</i> text
text <i>text text text</i> text
text<i>text </i>text text<i>text text</i> text
text <i>text</i> text text<i>text text</i> text
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry, I try to cover all possible cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
's:</i><i>::g'
```

That captures the basic idea that we want to get rid of an endtag followed by a new start tag, but fails when encountering;

(1) capitalised tags:

Replace 'i' with '[Ii]' to match capitalized html tags; if you want the capitalization to remain as it was, rather than replacing with a lowercase i, put the match within a `(group)` and have `\1` in the output side of the sed command.

(2) whitespace between the tags; to replace any number of spaces with a single space, we use an optional match group around the first space, which is put into the output:

```
's:</i>\(\ \)\?\s*<i>:\1:g'
```

The space and forward slash characters are escaped with a backslash, and the g at the end of each replacement allows it to match multiple times on each line.

(3) whitespace inside the tags should be matched with `\s` which captures both tabs and spaces. Oddly enough whitespace is allowed before the final `>` but not elsewhere in the tag. However, if a tag spans multiple lines you are screwed. Matching multiple lines is possible in sed but turns this into a script that is much too long for a single line.

After modifying for all three cases, the script line becomes:

```
sed -i 's:</[Ii]\s*>\(\ \)\?\s*<[Ii]\s*>:\1:g' yourfile.html
```

A note about the -i (in place replacement); this is an option in GNU sed, not standard sed. OSX has -i, but needs an extra `''` parameter after the -i. If your sed does not support -i, you need to redirect to a new file, then mv that file to replace the original:

```
sed 'the same command' > newfile.html
mv newfile.html yourfile.html
```

See the SO question: ['sed edit file in place'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place) for more information on that.

Comment: Your solution is not case insensitive as asked (/I) and I think it should be possible with a single replacement: `sed -r 's:</i>( )?[ ]*<i>:\1:gI'` Also, op did not mention this, but HTML tags can contain whitespace (even newlines) and still be valid, which would make things more complicated, if that were a requirement.

Comment: @ErikLievaart Thanks for the insight; using an optional group solves the problem neatly.

Comment: Amazing!!, thanks a lot for your help, for me is very useful :)