# Shell script issue with sed

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to run the following shell script on windows using `sh preprocess.sh` on cmd

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ./raw_data

# echo "download pretrained word embeddings: glove.42B.300d.zip"
# wget https://nlp.stanford.edu/data/wordvecs/glove.42B.300d.zip

# echo "unzip glove.42B.300d.zip"
# unzip glove.42B.300d.zip

echo "add vocab size and embedding size to the head of glove.42B.300d.txt"
n=$(sed -n '$=' glove.42B.300d.txt)
sed -i "1i$n 300" glove.42B.300d.txt

cd ..
echo "process raw data"
python process_raw.py

echo "prepare training, valid, testing data"
if [ ! -d "./log" ]; then
    mkdir log
fi
python preprocess.py > log/preprocess.log
echo "Finished! preprocess.log is saved in log directory."
```

However, I am getting the following error
[sed.exe: invalid option -- i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltRiN.png)

Can anybody please suggest a solution?

Comment: It seems that the -i flag is the causing the error (`invalid option -i`). What does a simple `sed -i infile` give you outside of your script?

Comment: What is the output of `sed --version`? Looks like you are using `sed` version without `-i` option.

Comment: -i option is a GNU extension, so don't expect all seds to support it

Comment: sed -i infile gives me invalid option --i

Comment: GNU sed version 3.02 @KamilCuk

Comment: That looks like a version of sed that is at least 15 years old. Update your sed or just don't use `-i` option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place)