# Deleting a hosts file entry on solaris using a script or command directly

Tags: bash, solaris

I have requirement where I want to delete a entry from /etc/hosts file matching a particular entry

For example

I want to delete an entry like below

```
192.168.1.1 test001 test001.test.test.com
```

How can I do this either using a single line command or a script.

Answer (score 0):

This deletes the string from your hosts file

```
sed -i -e "/192.168.1.1 test001 test001.test.test.com/d" filename
```

You might need regular expressions to catch whitespace between the words which might be blanks or tabs:

```
sed -i -e "/192.168.1.1.*test001.*test001.test.test.com/d" filename
```

Comment: `-i` is a non-standard, non-portable GNU extension to [the POSIX `sed` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and potentially not available on Solaris.  [GNU `sed` also does not do an actual in-place edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place), instead creating a temporary file, then renaming that temporary file to the original file name, thus actually deleting the original file.  Since `/etc/hosts` on Solaris is actually a link to `/etc/inet/hosts`, this answer will break that link.

Comment: Any other way we can achieve this

Comment: @YogeshDalal Use an `ed` script such as this:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493806/111943

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
grep -v "192.168.1.1 test001 test001.test.test.com" /etc/inet/hosts >/tmp/hosts
mv /tmp/hosts /etc/inet/hosts
```

The file and path differ because `/etc/hosts` in Solaris is softlink to `/etc/inet/hosts`