# place a comma before a bracket with sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a text formatted like following:

```
key [value]
key [value, value]
```

now I realized I forgot to put a comma between the key and the values array, which means I am trying to get this:

```
key, [value]
key, [value, value]
```

I thought, instead of regenerating the file which takes several hours, I could maybe easily do it with sed.
I tried `cat small.txt | sed -n 's/{ \[}/{, \[}/g'` and some other variants (like without {} and without spaces, I get no error, but the file doesn't change

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]])([[:space:]]+\[)/\1,\2/g' small.txt > newsmall.txt`

Comment: Yup it worked with the test file, can you put it as an answer so I can mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]])([[:space:]]+\[)/\1,\2/g' small.txt > newsmall.txt
```

Here, `-E` enables the POSIX ERE regex engine and the command does the following:

- `([[:alnum:]])([[:space:]]+\[)` finds an alphanumeric and places it in Group 1, then grabs 1+ whitespaces and a `[` into Group 2
- `\1,\2` - replaces the match with Group 1, then `,` and then Group 2 contents.

If you want to modify the file inplace, see [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125).