# How can I insert a text file at specific line of another

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I am dynamically generating some SDK code for multiple API sets and need to merge in subsets of files so that my ending import structure works.

I have a file, lets call it `methods_to_import.txt` of which I have already extractimed the lines I need to insert using:

```
awk '/method_imports_im_matching/{print}' file_i_need_to_copy_methods_from.rb > method_to_import.txt
```

I need to insert `methods_to_import.txt` at a specific line of the main file `my_api.rb` which looks something like like:

```rb
# Models
require 'models/account'
require 'models/account_type'
...

// the line I need to insert the text file into ( ex. line 10 )

# APIs
require 'my_api'

module My Class
  ...
end
```

I've figured out ways to overwrite the file completely: 
`echo "foo" > bar.txt`

or Insert a single string at a specific file line: `awk 'NR==3{print "Single String, but not the entire file output :("}1' my_api.rb`

> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271475/insert-text-at-specific-line-number

Perhaps I need to loop each line of the .txt file and insert line by line into the .rb file?

But I cant figure out how to insert the entire text file at a specific line of the existing file. I'm pretty sure it can be done with a combination of `sed` || `awk`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

will be simpler with `sed`

```
$ sed '/insert the text file/r methods_to_import.txt' my_api.rb
```

Comment: Great - yes thank you. So that outputs the exact file I need to stdout.

Comment: Of course, you can do `-i` but better to keep the old version around.

Comment: Solved with the following `sed -i '' '/# Models/r mehtods_to_import.txt' my_api.rb` needed an extra empty string for variable on mac ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place/12696224 ) Thanks Karakfa

Comment: your https://www.buymeacoffee.com/iqJPA2jMV page doesn't have a payment method setup ;)

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that. I have to remove it