# how to replace repetitive string of variable length with another string in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, replace

I have files where missing data is inserted as '+'. So lines look like this:

```
substring1+++++substring2++++++++++++++substring3+substring4
```

I wanna replace all repetitions of '+' >5 with 'MISSING'. This makes it more readable for my team and makes it easier to see the difference between missing data and data entered as '+' (up to 5 is allowed). 
So far I have:

```
while read l; do
  echo "${l//['([+])\1{5}']/'MISSING'}"
done < /path/file.txt
```

but this replaces every '+' with 'MISSING'. I need it to say 'MISSING' just once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use regex in Bash variable expansion. Use `sed 's/+\{1,\}/MISSING/g' <<< "$l"`. Or just without reading lines, `sed 's/+\{1,\}/MISSING/g' /path/file.txt`

Comment: Hi there! Nothing to add to the answer you select, it's perfect. Anyway, I think this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) could be useful for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use regex in Bash variable expansion.

In your loop, you may use

```
sed 's/+\{1,\}/MISSING/g' <<< "$l"
```

Or, you may use `sed` directly on the file

```
sed 's/+\{1,\}/MISSING/g' /path/file.txt
```

The `+\{1,\}` POSIX BRE pattern matches a literal `+` (`+`) 1 or more times (`\{1,\}`).

See the [`sed` demo online](https://ideone.com/eN815T)

```
sed 's/+\{1,\}/MISSING/g' <<< "substring1+++++substring2++++++++++++++substring3+substring4"
# => substring1MISSINGsubstring2MISSINGsubstring3MISSINGsubstring4
```

If you need to make changes to the same file use any technique described at [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125).

Comment: For making the change in file in line `-i` can be used

Comment: @DigvijayS It depends on the OS and sed version. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125) are more solutions for that.