# Replace Text using variables in Sed not working

Tags: unix, sed

I need to modify an xml file using Sed to replace the line

```
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ttpdbscan.axel.net:1521/axel.telco.net"
```

with

```
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ttpdbscan.axeltelecom.net:1598/axelPRD.telco.net"
```

I have stored the lines like this

```
ACTUAL_DB=$(sed -n 's#^.*url="\(.*\).*"#\1#p' $FILE.xml)
```

and

```
NEW_DB="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ttpdbscan.axeltelecom.net:1598/axelPRD.telco.net"
```

And the replacing method is this one

```
sed -i "s#$ACTUAL_DB#$NEW_DB#g" $File.xml
```

The problem is that when I run the script the file stays the same.

I have echoed the variables and all of them return the correct values.

Comment: although using `sed` to modify xml isn't advisable (use tools like xmlstarlet instead), I don't see any issue for the given sample and sed commands used..

Comment: what happens if you do `sed "s#$ACTUAL_DB#$NEW_DB#g" $File.xml > new.xml` does the new file has modified content?

Comment: Can you please add output of `echo ${ACTUAL_DB}`

Comment: `sed -i "s#${ACTUAL_DB}#${NEW_DB}#g" File.xml`? If `File.xml` is a path, you should not add `$` there.

Comment: when I echoed ACTUAL_DB, it shows the correct value.
I made a  test where I created another variable and assigned the  hardcoded text
the sed works with that new variable, and if I compare it to the one I'm getting it shows that they are the same

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file you have is `File.xml` (if it is not a variable), you may use

```
sed -i "s#${ACTUAL_DB}#${NEW_DB}#g" File.xml
```

Try also with other delimiters:

```
sed -i "s~${ACTUAL_DB}~${NEW_DB}~g" File.xml
```

If your `sed` does not support `-i` use

```
sed "s~${ACTUAL_DB}~${NEW_DB}~g" File.xml 1<> File.xml
```

See [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place)

Answer (score 0):

So I saved the output into another file and found out that the string had an extra space

so it looked like this

```
ACTUAL_DB= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ttpdbscan.axel.net:1521/axel.telco.net "
```

I removed the extra space with

```
"$(echo -e "${ACTUAL_DB}" | tr -d '[:space:]')"
```

And now the sed is working as intended