# What does <"$fileVariableName"> do in csh?

Tags: sed, csh

I am reviewing an existing script using sed commands in cshell, and I understand all of it except one component. I have simplified it down for sharing an example but below, $templateFile is used as input, and all instances of "hello" are replaced with "world", and once this is done, it is output to the output directory and named with the output file name.

`sed -e 's:hello:world:g' <"$templateFile"> "$outputDir"/"$outputFileName".txt`

However, I don't understand what the <> around "$templateFile" is doing? Why is it necessary to have the <> for a sed input file? In all descriptions of sed, I can't find an explanation for what purpose this might be serving so I am a bit confused.

I understand this is a simple question, but I cannot find an answer online and I'd appreciate any clarification here. Thank you.

Comment: It's not `sed`, it part of shell.

Comment: BTW, bash and csh are **completely** incompatible. No question should ever be tagged with both -- they're languages that aren't even from the same general lineage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<` and `>` are [stream redirection operators](https://superuser.com/questions/480599/with-regards-to-piping-commands-what-are-the-greater-than-and-less-than).

You do not need the `<` operator because `sed` accepts a filename argument after the sed command.

If you plan to save sed replacement result in a new file, `>` is required.  If you want to save the file contents "inline", there is no obligation to use `>` either. With GNU `sed`, you can do

```sh
sed -i 's:hello:world:g' "$templateFile"
```

With Free BSD `sed`, you can do

```sh
sed -i '' 's:hello:world:g' "$templateFile"
```

Check the [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place) question.

You do not need `-e` either, it only signals that the next argument is the sed command.

Comment: @MartinTournoij That is why I specifically used the `GNU` and `Free BSD` terms in my answer.

Comment: Sorry about that-- couldn't decide who to accept between you and Charles Duffy as you were both helpful but I'll do it now.

Comment: @JElder At least you helped me with my rep :) Charles has got [a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) of points already. And more rep means more features are available for you.

Comment: Oops, sorry; I missed that part somehow   How silly of me.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're reviewing has misleading use of whitespace. A more readable version might look like:

```
sed -e 's:hello:world:g' <"$templateFile" >"$outputDir/$outputFileName.txt"
```

As usual, `<infile` redirects stdin from `infile`, and `>outfile` redirects stdout to `outfile`.

Like other redirections, all this happens before `sed` is even started; `sed` itself has no bearing on or control over how the shell interprets these parts of the command.