# How to replace string-literal that takes the form of shell variable in bash/with sed?

Tags: bash, sed, replace, in-place

I'm familiar with `sed`'s ability to replace in-place in a file, as answered here: [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place).

I.e. `sed -i 's/STRING_TO_REPLACE/STRING_TO_REPLACE_IT/g' filename`

**I'm having trouble expanding this concept to replacing a string-literal that takes the form of a shell-variable -- how does one do this?**

To illustrate with an example:
Given file `file.txt`:

```
# file.txt
set(FOO ${FOO})
```

...and shell environment variable ${FOO}:

```
$ FOO=bar
$ echo ${FOO}
bar
```

...**how can I use sed to replace string-literal "${FOO}" in `file.txt` with the value of shell-variable `${FOO}` i.e. "bar"?** I.e. I'd like the resulting content of `file.txt` to be:

```
# file.txt
set(FOO bar)
```

I have a mental block thinking past the obviously-incorrect `sed -i 's/${FOO}/${FOO}/g' file.txt`

I gravitate towards `sed` because of past experience, and might prefer a `sed`-centric answer for the same reason. But any solution is probably okay, but with a preference for POSIX-compliance, if shell-native. To be even more specific, this is going to be run in a docker container with a `debian-10.3` base...so I suppose solutions that work with any tools included in that distro should be okay as well.

Comment: For sed use double quotes: `sed -i "s/\${FOO}/${FOO}/g" file.txt`

Comment: @anubhava - thank you; please post an answer if you're able to share details on your solution: why it works, what's different vs. my obviously-incorrect attempt, etc.