# Vagrant disable guest capability in Vagrantfile

Tags: linux, vagrant, opnsense

I would like to disable one specific guest capability: "persist_mount_shared_folder"
Is this possible somehow in the Vagrantfile?

**Reason:**
The setting "config.vm.allow_fstab_modification = false" does not work as expected by me and still tries to clean up the fstab file.
See: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/main/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb#L140
So, setting that setting to "false" only sets the synced_folder list to "nil", which leads in the capability "[persist_mount_shared_folder.rb](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/main/plugins/guests/linux/cap/persist_mount_shared_folder.rb#L20)" to try to remove all entries from fstab. (Which I did not expect to happen, because I set the setting do not allow for any modifications of the fstab file ...?)

I am building an OPNSense box (v21). Starting that box results in an error after connecting with SSH. The error is about the "sed" command which tries to cleanup the /etc/fstab file. Unfortunately that sed command does not work on this OPNSense version:

```
==> opnsense21: Machine booted and ready!
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

sed -i '/#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,/#VAGRANT-END/d' /etc/fstab

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:
sed: 1: "/etc/fstab": invalid command code f
```

The sed command is defined in "[persist_mount_shared_folder.rb line 66](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/aae8f4f4a5860d21bae9adbc409740279d172ee3/plugins/guests/linux/cap/persist_mount_shared_folder.rb#L66)" but I do not know how to alter this command. So that's why I am trying to disable the capability.
*The VM does not need any synced folders*

Comment: You have openbsd sed, not GNU. See ex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place _on macos_.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I thought of that, but I cannot change the sed command completely without recompiling Vagrant for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the issue myself by looking for other installed shells.
I found the 'tcsh' shell. Setting it as the default shell for the communication during vagrant provision the error does not happen anymore, and I can proceed.

`config.ssh.shell = "tcsh"`