# Adding a header paragraph to a file with bash script (and sed)

Tags: bash, sed

I have a basic bash script to generate a file conversion with pandoc.
After the file conversion I want to add a text header (jekyll darkmatter) before the first line.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Pattern #sed -i "s|abc|xyz|g" FILENAME.md

BIN="/home/jazio/Projects/jazio.eu/bin"
OUTPUT="/home/jazio/Projects/jazio.eu/_koines"


read -p "FILENAME (do not enter file ext) : " FILENAME
stat ${FILENAME}.odt

INPUT="/home/jazio/Projects/jazio.eu/assets/kerygma/${FILENAME}"



cd ${INPUT}
ls -als
trap 'echo fisierul e $INPUT/$FILENAME.odt' DEBUG
read -p "Press any key to start the conversion ..."
pandoc -s ${FILENAME}.odt -t markdown -o ${FILENAME}.md
stat ${FILENAME}.md
read -p "Press any key to start to resume ..."
# Insert darkmatter before the first line

sed '1 -i
 --- \ 
 layout: koine \
 title: ${FILENAME} \
 categories: [koine] \
 image: /images/koine/16_FB_ED_Four_Horsemen_1920.jpg \
 preview: \
 status: incomplet \
 tags: [koine] \
 order: 28 \n
 version: 1.2.7 \
 published: true \n
 comments: true \
 ---' FILENAME.md


cp ${OUTPUT}/${FILENAME}.md ${OUTPUT}/${FILENAME}.backup
cp ${INPUT}/${FILENAME}.md ${OUTPUT}
cd ${OUTPUT}
ls -als ${OUTPUT}

head ${OUTPUT}/${FILENAME}.md
```

Somehow the syntax of sed command is wrong.

Comment: Replace all \\ with single \ and you will need `-i` flag

Comment: won't some characters in `"$FILENAME"` possibly break the `sed` command?

Comment: What is that `sed` intended to do? Prepend some text to the file?

Comment: @KamilCuk exactly

Comment: @anubhava I still have no luck. It add nothing. The meaning of 1 is to add before the first line. Maye you can elaborate your answer?

Comment: It's ```sed -i -e '1 i \```  ```stuff '``` for GNU sed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place. `-i` is a flag, `i` is the command, see `man sed`.