# sed: bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Tags: sed

I'm trying to run a command on macos terminal. The command is to create a .txt file put a string inside of it and then replace a word inside of the .txt file.

I keep getting the error: `sed: bad flag in substitute command: '}'`

The commands

```
echo "This is a test file" > test2.txt
sed '/test/{s/test/test2/g}' test2.txt
```

I also tried:

```
echo "This is a test file" > test2.txt
sed '/test/\\{s#test#test2#g\\}' test2.txt
```

But the error here was: `sed: 1: "/test/\\{s#test#test2#g\\}": invalid command code \`
My assumption is I need to escape the characters but I'm unsure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands ends with a newline or with `;`.

```
sed '/test/{s/test/test2/g;}'
```

or

```
sed '/test/{s/test/test2/g
}'
```

but just:

```
sed '/test/s/test/test2/g'
```

Fun fact: empty regex repeats last regex, so you can just:

```
sed '/test/s//test2/g'
```

or really the address is not needed, just:

```
sed 's/test/test2/g'
```

Comment: When this done, I'd also like to save the result back into the test2.txt file, I tried using `sed -i 's/test/test2/g' test2.txt` but it produces an odd error; `sed: 1: "test2.txt": undefined label 'est2.txt'`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place note the "when on macos"